# Avoid reprovisioning a Vagrant VM if it is already provisioned

Tags: vagrant

I am trying to get a shell provisioner to avoid reprovisioning a VM instance if it has already done so previously.

Consider the following Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.define :minimal do |config|
    # Base image
    config.vm.box = "lucid32"
    config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box"

    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "mkdir /tmp/foobar"
  end
end
```

If you run `vagrant up minimal`, it will create the box and provision it initially. If you then run `vagrant provision minimal` it will attempt to reprovision the box but will fail (since the /tmp/foobar directory already exists).

Is there a way to make Vagrant remember whether it has provisioned a machine in the past and to avoid reprovisioning it later?

*More context: If I run `vagrant up minimal`, restart my host machine, and then run `vagrant up minimal` again, it will try to reprovision the box and fail. This happens reasonably often since VirtualBox frequently causes kernel panics on my host machine.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might not be the answer you want, but if you change that `mkdir` to a `mkdir -p`, it will work ;)

In all seriousness, though, I think Vagrant expects provisioners to be idempotent (that is, if run the second time, it will take no action).

It might be tricky to achieve true idempotency, depending on what you're actually doing in your provisioning script, but `mkdir -p` is a good start. You could also create a flag file on the system, and check existence of that flag file first thing; if it exists, just `exit 0`.

Comment: Making the provisioner idempotent seems to be reasonable. Although not necessarily easy.

Comment: I break my provisioning script into sections surrounded by if statements. I touch a file at the end of each section and the if statement checks to see if that file exists. So each section of code will only run once. This adds very little complexity, and I have functions for checking and writing the file to cut down on clutter. So far, this works pretty well.  I would also suggest that "test -d /path/to/dir || mkdir /path/to/dir" might be a better way of handling this particular problem.  There is also -f for files and -L for symlinks. "man bash" has more.

Comment: The simple and dumb way to create idempotency is to `touch ~/.VM_PROVISIONED` at the end of your provisioning (provided everything was successful) and check for its existence at the beginning via `[ -e ~/.VM_PROVISIONED ]`.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using a bash provisioning script, the odds are it will not be idempotent.

Here's a low brow example of how to avoid provisioning twice:

```
PROVISIONED="/some-app-dir/PROVISIONED";

if [[ -f $PROVISIONED ]]; then
  echo "Skipping provisioning";
  exit;
else
  echo "Provisioning";
fi

#...do provisioning things

touch $PROVISIONED;
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked into this?

`vagrant up --no-provision`

```
$ vagrant up --help
Usage: vagrant up [vm-name] [options] [-h]

    --[no-]provision             Enable or disable provisioning
    --provision-with x,y,z       Enable only certain provisioners, by type.
    --[no-]parallel              Enable or disable parallelism if provider supports it.
    --provider provider          Back the machine with a specific provider.
-h, --help                       Print this help
```

Comment: Using --no-provision looks like it will unconditionally avoid provisioning. Specifying the option conditionally using a script might do the trick, although it isn't ideal.

Answer (score 5):

Vagrant normally runs the provisioning code only on the *first* `vagrant up` *and* when you specifically tell it to do so, such as with `vagrant provision` or `vagrant reload --provision`.  There's really no need to go out of your way to avoid running the provisioning scripts again. (This [may not have been the case when you posted the question, however](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1776).)

If you're using Chef or Puppet for provisioning they're already designed to make everything [idempotent](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_why.html#idempotence), and I would assume the same is true for Salt and Ansible.

If you're using shell scripts and you want to make them idempotent, you can check for some condition (like the existence of a file) in an `if` statement:

```
if [[! -f "$HOME/bin/something.sh" ]]; then
  # install something.sh into ~/bin
fi
```

I've given a very general answer since I'm assuming that `mkdir /tmp/foobar` isn't *really* what you're trying to achieve, but if it is then yes, add `-p`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that only running the provisioner on first up is a relatively recent change (7 months ago).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not able to repro the error. Once a box is up, it's not supposed to provision unless you use facilities to explicitiy make it happen.

More importantly, provisioning should always be `idempotent` as noted by many others.

> **Idempotence** A recipe can run multiple times on the same system and the results will always be identical. A resource is defined in a
>   recipe, which then defines the actions to be performed on the system.
>   The chef-client ensures that actions are not performed if the
>   resources have not changed and that any action that is performed is
>   done the same way each time. If a recipe is re-run and nothing has
>   changed, then the chef-client will not do anything.

ref: https://docs.getchef.com/chef_why.html#idempotence

Comment: This seems to happen if, the first time you run `vagrant up --some-option`, it seems to remember that option. So the next time you run `vagrant up`, it will still pass `--some-option`.

I, myself, just got hit with that because someone documented to use `vagrant up --provision`... and after rebooting my machine, I did a `vagrant up`, and everything got wiped out.